# Find files that contain a string and do not contain another

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How do I find out the files in the current directory which do not contain the specific string but contain another? (by using grep)
I have most work done by this:

```
grep -L --include=\*.tf --include=file.hcl --exclude=versions.tf -rnw '.' -e 'string\s*\"string\"\s*'
```

and i have list of files taht don't contain this string. What to add?

Comment: `grep -L ... | xargs grep -l -e 'another' --` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a grep-pipeline. The following two are equivalent in speed (the second is slightly faster):

```
$ grep -lZ have_string * | xargs -0 grep -L avoid_string
$ grep -LZ avoid_string * | xargs -0 grep -l have_string
```

However, when you process a lot of files, it might be better to avoid reading files twice as this might be time-consuming. A single awk program might be beneficial in this case as it will only read the files a single time and perform early terminations if needed:

```
$ awk 'BEGINFILE{f=0}
       /avoid_string/{nextfile}
       /have_string/{f=1}
       ENDFILE{if(f) print FILENAME}
      ' *
```

This uses GNU-awk specific features which are not part of POSIX (`nextfile`, `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`). The awk lines does the following:

- `BEGINFILE{f=0}` when a file is opened for reading, set the flag `f` to zero. This flag keeps track if the string `have_string` is found in the file.
- `/avoid_string/{nextfile}`, for every line, check if the string `"avoid_string"` is part of the line. If it is, move to the next file
- `/have_string/{f=1}`, for every line, check if the string `"have_string"` is part of the line, if so update the flag `f` to indicate we found the string.
- `ENDFILE{if(f) print FILENAME}`: at the end of the file, check if we found the string `have_string`. If we did, print the filename'

Answer (score 0):

or u can make it much simpler, without all the extra blocks, and in a much more portable fashion :

> ```
>  mawk '
>  NF >= +/[.][0-9]+$/ {
>
>     if (NF == !_) { 
>          print FILENAME, $0
>     }
>     nextfile }' FS='N$' OFS='\f' 
>    
>            <(  date -j +'%T %D %s.%N' )
>            <( gdate    +'%T %D %s.%N' )
> ```

```
/dev/fd/12
          08:16:47 07/21/22 1658405807.574681000
```

cuz `bsd` `date` lacks nano secs, so placing the `gnu-date` `%N` formatting symbol there results in hideous epochs like `1658405807.N`

so in this example, the unwanted string is the `bsd-date` one with the `N` at the tail (which i set as `FS`). The total condition only hits true when either `NF` is greater than 1 (meaning the unwanted string was found), or when the right side regex evaluates to true (the desired string).

when either hits, it would enter the printing section. This is obviously a simplified scenario of course - you can simply use an array to save up all the filenames you've found with the desirable string, and delete them if you've found the bad one all of a sudden.

And instead of checking for `FNR == 1` all the time (something that has similar effect as `BEGINFILE { }` when emulated properly - slightly more hassle with workarounds for proper `NR/FNR` tracking,  but *much* more portable) -

simply add to the array when you've found the good string(s), delete from it and immediately `nextfile` once the bad one shows up, and only once all the files have been processed, in an `END { }` block, shall you proceed with printing out all the filenames still left inside the array.

my example used the shell `<( )` notation to emulate files coming in, that's why the filename printed look awkward, but you can see it indeed properly captured  the `gnu-date` one instead of the `bsd` one.

Comment: sory i'm beginer, can you explain what this do step by step?

Comment: @Remerio : how much do you understand so far